# Link or synch data from Access database to sql server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have front end form where users are entering information and details are getting stored onto an access database. I would like to have this data to be in sql server and users to continue use the same access form.

The schema is the same in sql server as in access .How do I achieve this?.

Comment: Is this a one-time copy, or are you trying to sync Access and SQL Server tables?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=access+link+sql+server

Comment: I am trying to synch access and SQL server , it is not a one time copy.

Comment: hi. why dont you just use the sql database for your backend?

Comment: My business users don't want to change it. They want to keep it the same.